# Use non-maven jar in maven project (using command line)

Tags: java, maven, jar

To start, I do not know much about maven or even jar's in general...

So basically I have been given a jar that was not created with maven to use in my maven project

Inside it has in it some classes:

```
com/something/types/Foo.class
com/something/types/Bar.class
com/something/utils/Foou.class
com/something/utils/Baru.class
etc.
```

I have tried running the following:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=something.jar -DgroupId=com.something.somethingelse \
        -DartifactId=somethingelse -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

and it says build success and has created the following:

```
~/.m2/repository/com/something/somethingelse/somethingelse/1.0/somethingelse-1.0.jar
~/.m2/repository/com/something/somethingelse/somethingelse/1.0/somethingelse-1.0.pom
```

in my project's pom I have included the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.something.somethingelse</groupId>
    <artifactId>somethingelse</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my project I import like so:

```
import com.something.types.Foo
import com.something.utils.Foou
etc.
```

But when I run `mvn install` on my project I receive errors like the following every time I try to use something from the jar?

```
[ERROR] {{ProjectClass.java}}[line,col] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Foo
[ERROR] location: class ProjectClass
```

Please help! I do not use eclipse.

Comment: sounds strange. What happens when you execute `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: same thing, errors reporting cannot find `class Foo` in `package com.something.types`

Comment: I will try to help sunday or monday.

Comment: its okay I got it figured out, ended up being a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process worked fine. The errors ended up being mistakes in my java code. For example:

```
import com.something.types.Foou       // my old code
import com.something.utils.Foou       // working import
```